# Jenkins Compare folders using command line in windows with error return in case they are not equal

Tags: command-line, jenkins

Is there a command which can compare two folders and return fail in case they are not exactly identical.

I need to add a folder compare in jenkins and fail build in case they don't match

Update: I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

There are a few commands that you could use. It depends a little bit on what you actually want to compare. The `cmp` command could be used.

`dircmp` is a similar to `cmp` but can be used on folders.

You could use this command in an if/then block, and add it as part of your Jenkins project.
It would look something like this:

```
if dircmp -s folder1 folder2; then echo "same"; else echo "different" 1>&2; exit 1; fi
```